# Serve images bigger than minimum file size in Nginx (and lua)

Tags: http, nginx, lua

I'm trying to check whether the requested file is above a certain size (say 250 bytes) and if so, serve the file, otherwise serve a default image.

However, I'm getting unexpected results. The line checking body length doesn't seem to be honoured and no_image_small.png gets served. res.status == 200 seems to work, though:

- request image size: **17** bytes
- no_image_small.png size: **3030** bytes

**nginx error log:**

```
2014/12/01 11:52:57 [error] 6033#0: *1 subrequests cycle while processing "/images/blue_image_small.jpg", client: 127.0.0.1, server: images.dev, request: "GET /images/blue_image_small.jpg HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/images/blue_image_small.jpg", host: "images.dev:8080"
2014/12/01 11:52:57 [error] 6033#0: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua:2: failed to issue subrequest: -1
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'capture'
    rewrite_by_lua:2: in function <rewrite_by_lua:1>, client: 127.0.0.1, server: images.dev, request: "GET /images/blue_image_small.jpg HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/images/blue_image_small.jpg", host: "images.dev:8080"
```

**My nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name images.dev www.images.dev;
    root  /home/syz/dev/images/;


    location ~* ^/images/(.*_small.) {
        rewrite_by_lua '
            local res = ngx.location.capture(ngx.var.uri)
            if res.status == 200 then
                local blength = string.len(res.body)
                if blength > 250 then
                    ngx.say(res.body)
                    ngx.exit(ngx.OK)
                else
                    ngx.redirect("/images/no_image.small.png")
                end
            else
                ngx.redirect("/images/no_image_small.png")
            end
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: How large is `no_image_small.png`? Is it less than 250 bytes? I'm no nginx expert but that error message looks like nginx caught that the handler would loop and killed the handler entirely.

Comment: no_image_small.png is 3030 bytes, the image I'm requesting in ngx.var.uri is 17 bytes. I'll add this to the question

Comment: So I think I was wrong to think about the image size at all. That's not part of the request handling itself that's part of the handler and nginx can't evaluate that without evaluating the handler and I doubt it is doing that a second time. Try not using a filename that matches that handlers pattern. I'm betting that will work. I think nginx is just seeing that the handler is requesting a redirect that will be handled by itself and disallowing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of capturing and reading the response body length, you can read the ***Content-Length*** header on your validation (it's faster).

I have a similar validation working in production, some like:

```
location ~*/img/.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg) {            
           set $max_image_size 15000;
           # default redirect if requested image too big
           error_page 412 = @default_image_loc; 

           #serving the content                   
           root  /local_server/root/;        

           #validating response
           header_filter_by_lua ' 
             local image_size = tonumber(ngx.header.content_length)                
             if image_size > tonumber(ngx.var.max_image_size) then
               ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE, string.format("invalid image size <%s>" , image_size))
               ngx.exit(412)
             end 
          '; 
}

location @default_image_loc {            
        try_files "/img/default_image.png" @none;            
}
```

The access log will remain clean as the 412 jump is internal.